# Im getting error Traceback (most recent call last): for i in num_guesses: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python

I'm getting int is not iterable and I'm not really sure what that means could someone please explain? My goal of this is to assign the guesses that the user input to the list user_guesses so that if user enters 952 the list is num_guesses = [9,5,2]

Code:

```
num_guesses = 3
user_guesses = []
number = ''
for i in num_guesses:
    number = input("Guess a number:")
    user_guesses.append(number)

print(user_guesses)
```

Comment: You can accept an answer if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `range`:

```
num_guesses = 3
user_guesses = []
number = ''
for i in range(num_guesses):
    number = input("Guess a number:")
    user_guesses.append(number)
print(user_guesses)
```

Or `while` loop:

```
num_guesses = 3
user_guesses = []
number = ''
while len(user_guesses)<num_guesses:
    number = input("Guess a number:")
    user_guesses.append(number)
print(user_guesses)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not iterate over an integer.You have to specify some range to iterate in for loop.
for example
for i in range(1,10)